# 1988 RX7 not starting, buzzing

Tags: electrical, starting, mazda, rx7

I recently obtained an RX7 and was told it worked fine but would not start due to the clutch going out while it was sitting some wires near the alternator were chewed by rats too, so after the wires and the clutch were all fixed I went to try to start it it won't turn over. When I connect the battery to it and turn the key I hear a loud buzzing sound coming from the engine bay, somewhere near the alternator, all the error and warning lights up on the dashboard also light up and a shift up light comes on the dash. If I turn the heater on the buzz goes away, but when I go to turn the key nothing turns over at all.

***The engine does turn over freely, I tried by hand.***

I will be checking for fuses/power tomorrow, and may be able to read an ecu error code if there are any, but I as wondering if anybody knew what could be causing this problem, thank you for any help!

Comment: what's the battery voltage?

Comment: The battery was dead so I had it connected to a 12v 10amp charger, also tried the jumpstart setting tooon the charger but no luck

Comment: What does it do.

Comment: Described it in the post, starter doesn't turn over at all, when I turn the key the lights dim a little and the buzzing stops. But whenever I turn the key to he on position I hear a loud buzzing noise from the engine near the alternator, and all the warning lights light up on the dashboard

Comment: Take the charger off, attempt to start, THEN measure the battery voltage.

Comment: Hey @IqbalKhan  How's it going?  Do you have a multimeter?

Comment: I do a multimeter, gonna be using it today to check some stuff

Comment: @steveracer would that matter because it's on a charger? I'm pretty sure the battery is beyond dead

Comment: Yes it matters, a dead battery will not start a car unless your "charger" is a professional unit that can source 100-200 amps.  Even that is a poor idea, because the battery acts like a capacitive "filter" that blocks some alternating current (AC) residue from the alternator and charger that is bad for sensitive electronics.  But the OCV check I described in my answer is the *definitive* test for the assumed "beyond dead" state of your battery.  The reason I said to remove charger and attempt start, is to remove "false charge" from gas bubbles that interfere with an accurate OCV measurement.

Comment: Changing the battery worked to stop the buzzing. Still won't turn over now though, all I hear is a click coming from the roof of the car, under the drivers visor somewhere

Comment: Sound likes some serious electrical issues I'd confirm the integrity of the ignition circuit. You're going to need wiring diagrams probably.

Comment: Gonna be checking thoroughly for any other chewed up wires the rats may have gotten to, or otherwise it may be time to check he whole starting circuit, I got some diagrams, just hoping it doesn't come to That!

Comment: So what was the voltage of the battery??  Did you check it?

Comment: Voltage was 0 - 0.05 volts, won't hold a charge whatsoever, the battery was definitely the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a lead plate weld broken inside the battery.  I would try a new battery, or at least determine if the battery is taking a charge before trying anything else.  You can measure the OCV "open circuit voltage" of the battery by connecting a voltmeter between the positive and negative terminals of the battery with the the car completely off.  And NO chargers of any type connected now or recently.

Anything below 11 volts warrants a new battery.  Really, anything below 12 volts is marginal.  My guess is yours will read 0-5 volts.  Dead.  Cannot be resurrected by any means other than replacement.

Comment: Battery was the problem for the buzzing, you were right, now when I turn the key, no buzzing from the engine. Everything electric works there is still a buzzing/long beep coming from the dash, but I think that's a low fluid warning if some type, whenever I go to start the car it still doesn't turn over, just a click from the roof near the visor

Comment: Gonna mark this as answered and open another question directed towards the starting issue since the buzzing and everything was related to the battery