# 1988 RX7 not turning over

Tags: electrical, starting, mazda, rx7

While trying to start my RX7 all I hear is a click coming from the dash when I turn the key.  When I stop turning the key to start it I hear another click coming from a relay above the visor located near the moon roof controls (see picture).

The battery is good and the engine does turn over freely by hand.  The car was broken into a couple times previously and I am wondering if maybe this could be some sort of theft lock prevention?

Are there any ideas out there whey I am unable to start my RX7?

Any help would be nice

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1988 RX7 not starting, buzzing](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/31667/1988-rx7-not-starting-buzzing)

Comment: As @Chenmunka pointed out, this looks like the issue stems from previous issues... Though TBH this is why FC rx7's have a reputation for electrical gremlins. I'd start by pulling out the main relay and checking it, then tracing back it's wiring and check the state of all the connectors and plugs.

Comment: the click behind the dash is likely the starter relay.  The click by the visor is likely triggered by the accessory circuit when the key backs back to the on position.  if you turn the key from off to acc, do you hear the visor click?  for troubleshooting the starter, get a test light and test at the relay and at the starter.

Comment: If this is considered a duplicate I can erase this one and add to my comments on my other question, I just wanted to isolate the issues so It could be searched by anybody else in the future with the same problem, seeing that the first issue on the previous question was all battery related, and this one was separate. But I did find the culprit, didn't realize there were two switches that get triggered by the clutch pedal, and one of them wasn't being pressed in all the way. Pushed it in by hand, and now it turns over fine!

Comment: Just added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason why it wouldn't turn over, it turns out the clutch safety switch was not being fully depressed when I pressed the pedal down and that was stopping power from getting to the starter. I pressed the switch down manually and it was able to turn over no problem.

Being my first time working on an Rx-7 when i found out about the clutch cutoff switch I looked under the pedal and tinkered with what i found out to be the cruise control cutoff switch, botch switches look very much alike.

So For any future reference, there are two switches that are triggered when you press the clutch pedal, one switch closes up, and when you press the pedal, and one switch gets pressed and opens up allowing the power to go to the starter. That switch is located more towards the firewall by the upper part of the clutch pedal near the master cylinder, that switch is the clutch safety switch which looks very similar to, but is not to be confused with the cruise control cutoff switch (correct me if I'm wrong) which is located towards the font/upper part of the clutch pedal.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution - I wish more people would do that. The archive is pointless without real answers.

Comment: No problem man, I totally agree, its frustrating  when you're trying to figure something out and you come across forums with a similiar problem but no answers, or someone just saying, "I fixed it!", hopefully this will help someone one day figure out the same thing I did, but quicker haha

Comment: See also https://xkcd.com/979/